# File upload, renamed automatically

Tags: atk4

When I do a file upload using FileStore, it automatically renames the uploaded file.

Is it possible to not do this? Because when I do a download, the real file name doesn't have an extension, and the client doesn't know how to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to setup mod-rewrite like this:

```
RewriteRule /upload/(.*).jpeg  $1  [L]
```

This way you can use extension "jpeg", and it would still point to the right file.

Leaving default filenames is insecure.